# Handling date in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures

I am working on a website in asp.net. I am getting a date from a web page and then depending on the user input I want to get results from SQL Server database (using stored procedures).

Problem is that I am getting date only from UI in this format `2016-10-08` which is of type string. But in the database, I have a column which is of type `datetime` in this format `2016-10-08 17:38:00.000`.

I am using this query to search but it does not work.

```
select * 
from table 
where acceptedDate like @sDate+ '%';
```

where `sDate` is input parameter for stored procedure. Please help. thanks

Comment: select * 
from table 
where convert(date,acceptedDate) >= @sDate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't pass dates as strings. Pass them as DateTime.
The .Net [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) [maps directly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx) to SQL Server's [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx). All you have to do is parse the string to a DateTime struct in your .Net code and pass it as a parameter to your stored procedure. 
To search for a specific date and ignore the Time portion of the DateTime, better use `>=` and `<` in your sql:

```
select * 
from table 
where acceptedDate >= @Date
AND acceptedDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @Date);
```

Comment: actually problem is i cannot find to parse input value into datetime. i am using input type=date to select date from calender.

Comment: i tried this but doesnot work String startDate = DateTime.Parse( txtstartDate.Value)

Comment: `String startDate = DateTime.Parse( txtstartDate.Value)` should not work, perhaps `DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse( txtstartDate.Value)`. I would suggest using `TryParseExact` instead of `Parse`, so that 1. you can control the acceptable formats, and 2 you will not get an exception if the string can't be parsed.

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want compare with day level and ignoring the hours part, you can use DateDiff function.
Pass d or DAY to interval parameter of DateDiff

For example:

```
DECLARE @sDate VARCHAR(100)='2016-10-08'
IF ISDATE(@sDate)=1
BEGIN
   select * 
   from table 
   where datediff(d,acceptedDate,@sDate)=0  --same day
END
ELSE 
 PRINT 'Invalid date format!'
```