# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException

Tags: c#, sql, api

I'm getting the error `$exception   {"An error occurred while reading from the store provider's data reader. See the inner exception for details."} System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException`

the inner exception says `InnerException    {"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."}   System.Exception {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}`

The URL I'm using is 2466:api/fullmessage/company/WaterMeter/2017-03-01/2018-04-01

this is the code i'm using:

```
public List<FullMessage> GetByCompanyTypeBetweenDays(string id, string type, string day1, string day2)
    {
        DateTime Day1;
        DateTime Day2;
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(day1, out Day1))
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(day2, out Day2))
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        };
        using (IoTdatabaseEntities entities = new IoTdatabaseEntities())
        {
            return entities.Database.SqlQuery<FullMessage>(@"SELECT *
            FROM [Messages] join [Devices] on [Devices].[DeviceID] = [Messages].[DeviceID]
            Where [devices].[company] = '@company' and [messages].[type] = '@type' and
            [Messages].[MessageSentDateTime] between '@FirstDay' AND '@LastDay'
            Order by [Messages].[MessageSentDateTime]
            ", new SqlParameter("company", id), new SqlParameter("type", type), new SqlParameter("FirstDay", Day1.ToString("yyyyMMdd")),new SqlParameter("LastDay",Day2.ToString("yyyyMMdd"))).ToList();
        }
    }
```

I tried to remove the `ToString("yyyyMMdd")` method but this still gave me errors

```
public List<FullMessage> GetByCompanyTypeBetweenDays(string id, string type, string day1, string day2)
    {
        DateTime Day1;
        DateTime Day2;
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(day1, out Day1))
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(day2, out Day2))
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        };
        using (IoTdatabaseEntities entities = new IoTdatabaseEntities())
        {
            return entities.Database.SqlQuery<FullMessage>(@"SELECT *
        FROM [Messages] join [Devices] on [Devices].[DeviceID] = [Messages].[DeviceID]
        Where [devices].[company] = '@company' and [messages].[type] = '@type' and
        [Messages].[MessageSentDateTime] between '@FirstDay' AND '@LastDay'
        Order by [Messages].[MessageSentDateTime]
        ", new SqlParameter("company", id), new SqlParameter("type", type), new SqlParameter("FirstDay", Day1), new SqlParameter("LastDay", Day2)).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong. the query works when I execute it in the database.

in this post, they removed the quotes around the dates and this just doesn't return anything at all
[Handling date in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41788157/handling-date-in-sql-server)

Comment: that is because in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119133/conversion-failed-when-converting-date-and-or-time-from-character-string-while-i they said that this would work however it doesn't fix the error

Comment: no, it then it still gives the error

Comment: how do I remove this duplicate thing?

Comment: You don't. It is a duplicate.

Comment: it gave me the same exact error

Comment: when I remove the`'` the API returns no records while it should be returning records

Comment: That is a different issue. You should raise a new question for that.

Comment: ok thanks ill make a new question