# How to get varchar date value and insert into dateTimePicker (C#, WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms, t-sql

In my program, I insert a dtp value to my TSQL database as so:

```
con.Open();
string sql = "insert into Table(Date)values('"+dateTimePicker.Value.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")+"')";
com = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

`con` and `com` are the predefined SqlConnection and SqlCommand respectively.

I save it in a `varchar(50)` format.

In my `Edit` form, I want to retrieve it through a `SELECT` statement and load it into the datetimepicker.

How do I do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection

Comment: You should really store DateTime objects, not strings. Then format a DateTime as required in your UI.

Comment: As Chris (probably) wants to say with his link: Don't concatenate strings for SQL statements like above. Use parameterised statements to avoid SQL injection.

Regarding your Question: Would you like to insert a `DateTime` into the database or retrieve it *from* a database for a `DatePicker`? That's not clear...

Comment: @Gorgsenegger I said this: "In my `Edit` form, I want to retrieve it through a `SELECT` statement and load it into the datetimepicker." Yeah. I want to retrieve the varchar date and load it into a datetimepicker.

Comment: But your code snippets does not say this. It looks like writing to the database.

Comment: @MuzafferGALATA I know. This is how I inserted into the database. I want to know how to retrieve `dateTimePicker.Value.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")` from the database and load it into a dateTimePicker.

Comment: If you like to get data from the Database look if this link helps you from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1 and then try for the value *Convert.ToDateTime(myvalue)*

Comment: Three links that will help you solve your problem: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type), [Back to basics: SQL Injection](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2020/07/16/back-to-basics-sql-injection/), https://stackoverflow.com/a/41788202/3094533.